# Is it possible to implement equal operator in ES6?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to implement equal operator in ES6?

Instead of implementing an `equals()` method in class it would be nice to use 
`if (myClassObject1 === myClassObject2) {}`

Can we implement custom math operators in es6 javascript classes?

In c# it is possible to override it as follows

```
public static bool operator ==(Complex x, Complex y)
{
   return x.re == y.re && x.im == y.im;
}

public static bool operator !=(Complex x, Complex y)
{
   return !(x == y);
}
```

Comment: Said this already quite too often but comparing objetcs indicates a bad approach in 99.99% of the time. First problem: what is equal? Same properties? Same identifier? same instance? You should stay away from this approach

Comment: I added an example from C# language to explain better what I mean.

Comment: @Aaron I don't see why comparing objects indicates a bad approach. It is a reasonable thing to want to do that sadly JS makes a little awkward.

Comment: @sdgfsdh I think he means comparing a complete object which might be large.

Comment: @StephanAhlf In other languages it is common to create classes for smaller types and identifiers such as guids, date-times, vectors etc. For these cases it would be nice if `==` could be defined. Since JS does not have this it pushes people to use strings or numbers for everything.

Comment: I get what you mean @sdgfsdh I was just thinking about "real" objetcs not just helper classes. But I'd still prefer a function over over-riding tje default == Operator. Just personal opinion of course

Comment: It has big consequences for the language. For example, `Set` does not work intuitively in JS because of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

The `==` and `===` operators are explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), and they cannot be changed by the programmer.

A typical work-around is define an "equality" function and use that. For example, using the one from `lodash`:

```js
const a = { name: 'Alireza' };
const b = { name: 'Alireza' };

_.isEqual(a, b); // true
```

Brendan Eich discusses adding "Value Objects" [here](https://www.slideshare.net/BrendanEich/value-objects).

Comment: I do not want to change the operator it self. I want to change the the behavior objects will behave when the operator is used.

Comment: @StephanAhlf the `==` operator is defined globally, not on each `object` or `class` as you would find in C#.

Comment: Well in fact it is a little bit a dubios link you provided in 2nd. here it is for me the most important information regarding to my question.